# Copying from Spreadsheet to another Spreadsheet error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a total beginner using appscript, can someone please help me to resolve this error.

> The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

```
function Input1() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10xap9qOf487MB9M9FQ-Turp81X_ZIoDVMyFY-Puf9BU');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Input'); // ss = source sheet
  var values = ss.getRange("A2:H2").getValue();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1thJ5uqhfwZhdxsE0B9MhyhjwcFZpe4A0Ty3erGIuWpU');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Entries'); // ts = target sheet
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,1,8).setValues(values);        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take the values in the Range A2:H2 on Sheet "Input", and copy them to the row following the last row on Sheet="Entries".

The problem is in this line of code:
`var values = ss.getRange("A2:H2").getValue();`

Instead of using `getValue()`, you should use `getValues()`

Your range is 8 columns wide:

- `getValue()` "returns the value of the top-left cell in the range". In this case it returns the value of a single cell=A2.
- `getValues()` will return "the rectangular grid of values for [the] range". This is just what you want so that you can use it with the `setValues()` method in the last line of the script.